# Is there a way to extract the project URL and latest available version from a gradle dependency?

Tags: json, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to extract info about gradle dependencies from `build.gradle` and package it into a JSON string for use somewhere else.

A small example of what I am trying to do:

From `app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
}
```

I would like to obtain (in JSON) something like this:

```
...
{
    "name": "androidx.appcompat:appcompat",
    "source": "google",
    "installed": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "latest": {
        "version": "1.1.0"
    }
    "projectUrl": "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html",
    "license": "Apache 2.0 <http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0>"
}
...
```

So far I have managed to get half of the info like so:

```
configurations {
    myConfig.extendsFrom implementation
}

task printSolvedDepsTreeInJson {
    doLast {
        def jsonOutput = "["
        configurations.myConfig.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.each { dep ->
            def addToJson
            addToJson = { resolvedDep ->
                jsonOutput += "\n{\n"
                jsonOutput += "\t\"name\": \"${resolvedDep.module.id.group}:${resolvedDep.module.id.name}\",\n"
                if (resolvedDep.module.id.group.contains("android") || resolvedDep.module.id.group.contains("google")) {
                    jsonOutput += "\t\"source\": \"google\",\n"
                } else {
                    jsonOutput += "\t\"source\": \"jcenter\",\n"
                }
                jsonOutput += "\t\"installed\": {\n\t\t\"version\": \"${resolvedDep.module.id.version}\"\n\t},\n"
                jsonOutput += "},"
            }
            addToJson(dep)
        }
        if (jsonOutput[-1] == ',') {
            jsonOutput = jsonOutput[0..-2]
        }
        jsonOutput += "\n]"
        println jsonOutput
    }
}
```

But I cannot find any documentation on how to find the latest version for the gradle dependency (and I know this information is there somewhere, since Android Studio gives you a `lint` message about a newer version). I also would like to include a URL to the dependency (e.g. a github link if it's open source), which again I think should be possible since I found this [gradle plugin that can generate a JSON report which lists the website the project is from](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin#report-format).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not depend on that exact plugin you mention ([Ben Manes' Gradle Versions Plugin](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin)) to do the work for you? You can depend on the `dependencyUpdates` task and then parse the output for use in your own report.

Otherwise, you could have a look at how that plugin is implemented. I believe it duplicates the configurations, but with a dependency resolution rule that substitutes the version with the dynamic declaration `latest.release` (see documentation for that [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:declaring_dependency_rich_version)) and then lets Gradle resolve it.